# Failed to export a model based deformable DETR! The exported model can't work

Tags: deployment, pytorch, export, trace, torchscript

I try to export a pytorch model base on deformable DETR in order to deployment, but the exported model seems have some problem: it only can inference on the image that I used to export the model, but when I change another image, it can't work and it shows the error massage:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJWss.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MIRW.png)

All I'm expecting is to export the model, and it can inference on various images.